# How to debug in VS using Mono for android?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

It seems that if I put a breakpoint somewhere in my Visual Studio it doesn't do anything if I compile my app in Debug mode. (like the code never reaches that point although it actually does). Is there another way for debugging with Mono?(using VS IDE)

What am I doing wrong, why can't I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you it has to do with symbols. Breakpoints will be ignored if symbols cannot be understood by Visual Studio and to my knowledge Visual Studio only reads PDB files while Mono has it's own format. Now, I think you can produce PDB files with Mono but have you checked that the symbols are OK?

Comment: I am sorry but how can I check it?

Comment: When you launch a debugging session there's a item called symbols under the debug menu. Open this dialog and if you have any problems with your symbols, you'll see that your executable doesn't have any loaded symbols.

Comment: Here, I debugged the app and I don't see any item called symbols: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/5347/84304552.png

Comment: Open the Menu Bar Debug > Windows > Symbols, this menu item is only visible during a debugging session.

Comment: I feel very noobish but I really don't find it ><, maybe there's something related to it in that link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx I am sorry I just can't find it.

Comment: My bad, it's called Modules, look here http://i.imgur.com/n5jYh.jpg it's a VS 2012 screen shot but it's the same in VS 2010

Comment: heh, the debugging actually works now, i have no idea why, anyway i checked with the modules thingy and there wasn't any activity over there, that means anything?

Comment: You're supposed to find your executable there and your're supposed to be able to see that the symbols have been loaded, otherwise no breakpoints will be hit. Symbols can even be loaded but if file and line information is missing VS won't know how to map your breakpoints in code back to breakpoints in the code/process, it could be that your PDBs are incomplete.

Comment: Thank you for your effort helping me, I'm going to accept your answer because of your effort, last question: Is there anything to do about it? like, can I fix this situation or that fix isn't controlled by me?

Comment: @Chessebaron says it's a bug in Mono, if the PDBs are damaged there isn't really anything we can do. But this is the way to go about diagnosing what causing issues with symbols.

Comment: I see, well last question now serisouly, sorry for digging, I tried to read about these PDBs files and symbols but didn't really understand what these are, could you please explain it to me in a very short manner? Thank you once again.

Comment: PDB files are program databases, they contain information from the compiler on what it did with the source code. This information is necessary for debuggers to trace back the executing code to it's original source. It's a map that tells your debugger where all the assembly stuff in your image (binary) actually originated. So when you put a breakpoint in a source file the debugger uses the PDB to figure what address this corresponds to and then waits for an interrupt signal to break into your code. This is how debuggers know when to stop your program and let you look at it.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much for your explanation and effort helping me, appreciated, be safe!

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a bug in Mono for Android 4.2.3 which causes this behavior.

A bug report has been filled and can be seen here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5806

To temporarily fix this revert back to a previous version of Mono for Android.

Comment: There is something similar here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4725 the bug should be fixed for 4.2.4, the other bug I linked was only in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Quite often actually, sometimes within a couple of weeks sometimes it may take a couple of months. But if you really need the debugger, you can install VS2012 or you can use M4A 4.2.1 which should work just fine.

Comment: Nah, I will just use the MonoDevelop IDE for now, it doesn't really matter for me as for now. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you aren't using the Linker.  I couldn't debug in VS until I switched Linking to None in the Mono Android Options.